# Send array as message in discord.js

Tags: arrays, discord, console, discord.js

```
if (message.toLowerCase === '$bl') {
    console.log(bannedWords.join(', '))
}
```

bannedWords is previously defined as bannedWords = data.bannedWords and data.bannedWords is the following array: ["bla1", "bla2", "bla3"]
For whatever reason, I cannot get the bannedWords array to send as a log in console.
FYI, bannedWords' array is defined awkwardly because there are other commands that add/remove things to the array, which work fine (for now).

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to invoke the `toLowerCase` method.  Simply add a `()` to make it `toLowerCase()` and it should fix your issue.

Edit: PS, do you need to use `message.content`?  Generally, `message` is the object while its `content` property is the actual string.

Comment: Yes it must be `message.content.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to discord.js, and I'm just trying to remember as much as I can. This was a big help, thank you!